# Hardy Spaces: Meaning of $\frac{1}{z}\mathcal{RH}_\infty$

Tags: notation, normed-spaces, control-theory, hardy-spaces

### Question

I'm reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04815) (p.4) on linear systems where the authors silently introduce the notation for the set

$\frac{1}{z}\mathcal{RH}_\infty$.

Unfortunately I don't get the meaning of the notation nor can't I even describe in words what this is meant to be (so I don't know what to Google for...). Can you help me on that?

---

#### What I know / assume:

$\mathcal{H}_2$ and $\mathcal{H}_\infty$ are Hardy Spaces for functions with bounded 2- / respectively infinity-norm, and (as described in the paper) $\mathcal{RH}_2$ and $\mathcal{RH}_\infty$ are the set of real-rational strictly proper / proper transfer matrices.
This still makes sense to me.

**The paper covers discrete time systems, so I guess that $\frac{1}{z}$ is about an additional property in the z-domain, but what exactly?**

I know the following definitions of the $\mathcal{H}_2$ and $\mathcal{H}_\infty$ norms (taken from "Multivariable Feedback Control" by Skogestad) for continuous-time systems:

If $G(s)$ is a (matrix valued) transfer function, then

$\|G(s)\|_2 = \left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \|G(j\omega)\|^2_F d\omega \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where $\|G(j\omega)\|^2_F = \sum_{ij} |G_{ij}(j\omega)|^2$ is the Frobenius norm

and

$\|G(s)\|_\infty = \max_\omega \bar\sigma (G(j\omega))$ where $\bar\sigma (G(j\omega))$ is the largest singular value of $G(s)$ at $s=j\omega$.

(The above definitions are generalizations of the scalar valued definitions $\|f(s)\|_2 = \left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(j\omega)|^2d\omega \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\|f(s)\|_\infty = \max_\omega |f(s)| = \lim_{p\to\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(j\omega)|^pd\omega \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$).

Keywords for text search: H2, H inf, H infinity, H$\infty$, RH2, 1/z RH inf, 1/z RH infinity, 1/z RH$\infty$

Comment: I am not familliar with the topic but if I had to guess, I would say $f\in \frac{1}{z} X$ if $z f \in X$.

Comment: @calvin-khor I think you just somehow lead me into the right direction :-) Will post an answer with what I think is an explanation for the notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @calvin-khor and a supervisor I have an answer to it now.

#### TL;DR

---

**$\frac{1}{z}\mathcal{RH}_\infty$ denotes** the set of discrete time real proper transfer function matrices which have been delayed by one timestep and thus it's simply **the set of discrete time real strictly proper transfer function matrices**.

---

#### Background

A transfer function being proper means that it can be expressed as a fraction of two polynomials where the degree of the denominator polynomial's degree is greater or equal than the numerator polynomial's.

Such a transfer function can be written as the sum of a subsystem that is given by a differential equation (continuous time) or difference equation (discrete time) *and* a direct feedthrough term.
This means that the impulse response can start earliest at $t=0$, i.e. $g(t) = 0 \quad \forall t<0$ (CT) respectively $g[n]=0 \quad \forall n<0$ (DT).

Similarly, strictly proper transfer functions have $\deg(\text{denominator})>\deg(\text{numerator})$ and thus lack the feedthrough term.
For a DT system this means that the impulse response can start earliest at $n=1$.

A property of the z-Transformation is that a time shift, expressed as $f[n-k]$ (here a delay if $k$ positive), translates into $z^{-k}F(z)$ in the z-domain. So a factor of $\frac{1}{z}$ delays the whole impulse response by $1$.

---

(But this now begs the question - why not simply write $\mathcal{RH}_2$? I suspect the authors of the paper still see a minor difference between the two sets.)